# Crystal Reports toolbar is gone after upgrading from VS2008 to 2010

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, asp.net-4.0

I converted our web site to asp.net 4.0 in VS 2010. Crystal reports (version 10.5.3700.0) renders the reports, but the toolbar will not display (so the print/change page functionality is gone).

I have set `AspCompat="true"` in the page that hosts the viewer, and tried just about every combination in the properties for the viewer, but the toolbar will not render. I have also tried different `ClientIDModes`, nothing seems to work.

The only work around I have come up with so far is to set `SeparatePages="False"` in the viewer and display the report on one page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because crystal reports has a different set of libraries for 2010.

you need to install the updated version the files can be found here ...

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Not sure why ... this is likely something to do with API changes in visual studio but make sure you uninstal the older version first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The installer for 2010 came out shortly after I posted this (it was in beta at the time). I will mark this as the answer for future users.