# Toolbar is missing in Crystal Report Viewer (version 13)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using the latest version of Crystal Report in my ASP.Net web application project. My IDE is Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.6.

My problem is that when I run the aspx file that contains the Crystal Report Viewer, the toolbar is missing. Please see the attached image:
[image]

I already tried copying the toolbar folder to my root folder. I also tried hard-coding `ToolbarImagesFolderUrl`. I also tried copying crystalreportviewers from inetpub/wwwroot to my root folder. But nothing solved my problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535339/crystal-reports-toolbar-is-gone-after-upgrading-from-vs2008-to-2010

Comment: I am running the latest crystal report version. I have this another asp.net project with crystal reports and it's working properly. But this one isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the default table css in Visual Studio 2012 projects.  Remove the table, th, td, and tr stuff under tables and it will fix it.  I just spent almost a whole day trying to figure out why it was doing this.

Comment: thanks - this worked for me. The table css referred to is in Site.css in the Content folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this issue on

SAP Community Netwrk: Crystal Report for VS 2012. It is not appear as a option in Reporting. http://scn.sap.com/message/13828750

Redist packages are for deploying your project only. Uninstall them and then use the complete package install:

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe

Now you should not have to do anything except possibly adding the Viewer to the tool box.

Click on your form and then the Tool bar and then select Choose New Item and browse to this:

[toolbar items http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-13834457-182961/pastedImage_0.png](http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-13834457-182961/pastedImage_0.png)

Now you should see:

[Reportviewer] http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-13834457-182962/pastedImage_1.png](http://scn.sap.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-13834457-182962/pastedImage_1.png)

Not sure if the warnings are because you have not installed it correctly. If the above doesn't work then add the PATH to CR runtime to the project:

I don't believe you need to go this far down but this is where they exist on a DEV PC:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet

Runtime only they are only in the GAC.

Comment: I am using the complete Crystal package. I am able to add CrystalReportViewer without any problem. But when I run it on IIS the toolbar icons are missing.

Answer (score 0):

copy the aspnet_client folder from the default web site to your app website

Answer (score 0):

If the above issue is not resolved with web.config entry then press F12 in chrome. Click on console, find the files missing having .axd extensions. Create a blank notepad file and save with same name and extension. Place in the location where it is not found. Your problem will be resolved.